# Can I access the content-type form a blob/inputFile?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, form, apexinputfile

I'm writing a component to upload some files to AWS/S3. How can I detect the content-type of the upload form inputFile or from a Blob of the file in Apex?

```
 req.setHeader('Content-type', getInputFileContentType.ContentType);
```

What can I use in place of `getInputFileContentType`?

**Update**

If I get it from the blob instance of the file (`fileBlob.ContentType`) I get this error:

```
Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Blob (Line: 273)
```

What's going on?

Comment: Where is the blob coming from? Visualforce, callout, attachment record, static resource...?

Comment: Sorry, from parsing a form. I think I've got a fix though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need a getter and a setter in the controller:

```
public String contentType { get; set; }
```

And a matching attribute in the inputFile:

```
<apex:inputFile id="postFileId" fileName="{!fileName}" fileSize="{!fileSize}" value="{!fileBlob}" contentType="{!contentType}" />
```

Ta da.